# May a Jew act as a godparent to a Christian child?

Tags: gentiles, christianity, children

A Jewish friend was recently asked to be serve as a [Godparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godparent) (Godfather) to the child of his Christian friend. I would like to know if a Jew may accept such a request and if not why not.

Comment: Interesting question. The reverse - a gentile serving as a sandak at a Jewish brit is not allowed. Does this particular case require the godparent(s) to be present at the Christening? Because in some cases a godparent is just a type of secondary legal guardian - which is also a question, but probably less problematic than actually attending a Christian ceremony.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godparent) says that the godparent

> is someone who bears witness to a child's christening and later is
>   willing to help in their catechesis (basic Christian religious
>   education), as well as their lifelong spiritual formation.
>
> In both religious and civil views, a godparent tends to be an
>   individual chosen by the parents to take an interest in the child's
>   upbringing and personal development, to offer mentorship or claim
>   legal guardianship of the child if anything should happen to the
>   parents.

It seems obvious to me that it is not the role of a Jewish person to instruct others in their own religion.

If the requested role is purely civil, I see no major objection. But the friend should CYLOR.